# Using properties in javascript to change colours

Tags: javascript, properties

I am building a battleships game in **JavaScript** and I am currently using OOP to make a system that

a) selects a coordinate to place the boat

b) finds the next adjacent tiles to the boat

c) colours them in brown

I want to work on step c) for now, ie. choosing a coordinate, and changing its property hasBoat to 1, and then turning it brown. Is there a simple way that I can do this? The code is here:

```
var xPos;
var yPos;
var boatPos;
var boatGrid = {

    selectPos : function() {
        console.log("it works"); 
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
            this.hasBoat = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos);
            if (this.hasBoat == 1) {
                this.hasBoat.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            }
            this.buildBoat();
        }
    },
    buildBoat : function() {
        console.log("this works too");
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            xPos = xPos++;
        }
    },
}

function placeBoat() {
    document.getElementById(boatPos) = boatGrid.selectPos();
    boatGrid.hasBoat = 1;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your code has a number of errors in it.(`this.hasBoat.style.backgroundColor = "brown";` numbers don't have a `style` property) Could you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the partially functioning program and describe what you have done to try and solve the problem?

Comment: `boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
    this.hasBoat = 1;
    document.getElementById(boatPos);
    if (this.hasBoat == 1) {
     this.hasBoat.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
    }`

Comment: Umm... Why did you copy that section of code and post it as a comment? It's still broken and doesn't change anything.

Comment: This is the core of the code - boatPos is a coordinate for the grid, which is written as "cell_2_4" When it has chosen this coordinate randomly, I want to set the property "hasBoat" to 1. After all of the coordinates that have boats on are set to one, I want to change them all to brown. Is there a simple way that you can see of setting all of them to brown?

Comment: Are you just blatantly ignoring what I'm saying? I understand what you're trying to do and I've obviously read your code. I'm saying that your code is very, very broken. Have you looked at your console? (hit F12 on Windows or Opt+Cmd+I on Mac) You need to address some fundamental issues before anyone can give you meaningful help.